# Why is Google reporting no authorship when I created the link?

Tags: seo, google-plus

I wrote a guest blog post that's located here:

http://www.thestaffingstream.com/2013/10/08/finding-the-ideal-registration-form/

At the bottom I have my name linked to my G+ profile with the author relationship, as specified by Google to establish relationship:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/106760848386479083427?rel=author" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://plus.google.com']);" target="_blank">J. Pablo Fernández</a>
```

I assume the onclick and target is added by their CMS. Could that stop G+ authorship from being detected?

I'm testing whether G+ authorship is being detected or not here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thestaffingstream.com%2F2013%2F10%2F08%2Ffinding-the-ideal-registration-form%2F

For other pages that I'm the author of, not only the authorship works but also a search result displays my picture and name, for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=to+shortlist+or+not+to+shortlist+pablo

Comment: John, my question doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that other one, as the symptom I'm seeing is different and I can see my profile being shown for other pages.

Comment: Unfortunately troubleshooting specific pages is out of the scope for this website.